# Can a string be compared with a key value from firebase realtime db using flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to flutter and firebase and am trying to display the data of the current user that has logged in. I tried various ways myself like storing the current user email on a String variable and comparing it with they email key, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Is there a way to get the snapshot as output of only the logged in user data?

[image: Database]

```
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:helloworld/tictactoe.dart';
import 'package:helloworld/numbergame.dart';
import 'package:helloworld/profile.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Search',
      home: Search(),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'search';
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("insertdata");
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String? userEmail;
  void getCurrentUserEmail() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser;
    userEmail = user!.email;
  }
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUserEmail();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    //btmnavbar

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: FutureBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
          future: dbRef.once(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              lists.clear();
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
              values.forEach((key, values) {
                lists.add(values);
              });
              return new ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: lists.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Name: " + lists[index]["Email"]),
                          Text("Age: " + lists[index]["First Name"]),
                          Text("Type: " + lists[index]["Last Name"]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Which value in the database screenshot you shared identifies the current user?

Comment: The user logs in using the Email. So the email used for authentication of account and the email in the database are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user's email address, you can use a query to select just the nodes with that value in their `Email` property with:

```
future: dbRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo("hiba@gmail.com").once(),
```

Or if you have a variable `userEmail` with the email address in it:

```
future: dbRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(userEmail).once(),
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) from the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to output the data without providing the email address on the code. That is what im specifically looking for.

Comment: @User101 By using the variable `userEmail` instead of the String? `orderByChild(userEmail)`

Comment: As @Dabbel commented you can indeed substitute the hard-coded string for a variable with that same value. I've updated my answer to show that too. --- @Dabbel: you need to pass the variable to `equalToValue`, not to `orderByChild`.